# Persist form value on new user registration (devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a new user registration form and I would like to persist the values in the form if the validations fail. I did not see a way to do this.

Right now in my controller I have

```
def create
  .....code......
  @user = User.new params[:user]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url(@user)
end
```

However, this is not working. What needs to be done to accomplish persistent values after validation?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to redirect on validation failures.  You should render the `new` action (or whatever is appropriate in your situation).  A redirect will not have access to any of the instance variables from the calling context; it's essentially a completely new request.  The typical setup is something like this:

```
def SomeController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @foo = Foo.new
  end

  def create
    @foo = Foo.new(params[:foo])
    if @foo.save
      redirect_to foo_path(@foo)
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

end
```

The `render action:` here can be a little confusing.  It doesn't actually call the action; instead it renders the default view for that action.  In this case, if the `Foo` fails to save, it will render the `new` form, but instead of being populated with a new `Foo`, it will be populated with the `Foo` that failed to save.  So you'll get all the values in your form again.  Typically when you render the form (or in your layout), you will also check for and render any errors that might exist on the model (`@foo`).

Comment: thanks!, I ended up changing the code back to the original create method for devise and it got back to working again. I will keep this in mind in the future